# Cannot install YUM in MacOS

Tags: macports, yum

I'm trying to run the build script from [HTML5 Boilerplate](http://html5boilerplate.com/docs/Build-Script-Wizard/#requirements) and I have to install YUM for that. I am on **Mac OS Snow Leopard 10.6.8**. When I did `sudo port install yum`, i'm getting the following error. Any idea how can I rectify it and install yum properly?

```
--->  Computing dependencies for py24-nose
 --->  Dependencies to be installed: py24-distribute
 --->  Activating py24-distribute @0.6.24_0 Error: Target org.macports.activate returned: Image error:
 /opt/local/lib/python2.4/site-packages/setuptools-0.6c11-py2.4.egg-info
 already exists and does not belong to a registered port.  Unable to
 activate port py24-distribute. Use 'port -f activate py24-distribute'
 to force the activation. Error: Failed to install py24-distribute Log
 for py24-distribute is at:
 /opt/local/var/macports/logs/_opt_local_var_macports_sources_rsync.macports.org_release_ports_python_py-distribute/py24-distribute/main.log
 Error: The following dependencies were not installed: py24-distribute
 Error: Unable to upgrade port: 1 Error: Unable to execute port:
 upgrade py24-nose failed To report a bug, see
 <http://guide.macports.org/#project.tickets>
```

Previously after installing YUM, i was getting `Segmentation Fault`, so I uninstalled and installed it again using Macports to get the above error.

Comment: Did you try the command `port -f activate py24-distribute`?

Comment: I did that and it installed the YUM. But after that when i did `yum install ant-contrib` it gives me `Segmentation Fault` - the same as my first errors. Any idea? Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you've got the wrong end of the stick here. You **do not** need to install YUM on the Mac. In fact, that act is sheer madness, because you already have a perfectly good package manager in the shape of MacPorts!

Read again what it says

> If you're on Mac or Linux...
>
> You've got all your dependencies pre-installed, likely. You may need a yum install ant-contrib or what have you.

The key bit there is "or what have you". That is a cryptic way of saying "or the equivalent command for your package manager". On Red Hat-based systems, the package manager is indeed YUM; on Debian systems, it's APT; on the Mac, it's MacPorts.

So, remove your YUM installation, and simply do:

```
port install ant-contrib
```

You can now proceed to actually running Ant.

Comment: Thanks Tom for the clarification. Got Ant working through macports installation.

Comment: I get `port: command not found` when I try to run this command in Terminal on 10.6.8.